# Realtime databse endAt method doesn't work if I use variable in that

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
"Posts" : {
"-MnLFAlhayTv80FxzUfL" : {
  "description" : "",
  "picture" : "",
  "postKey" : "-M",
  "timeStamp" : 1635682139495,
  "title" : "",
  "userId" : "",
  "userPhoto" : ""
},
"-MnLFzItc050Sn0EtDho" : {
  "description" : "",
  "picture" : "",
  "postKey" : "-M",
  "timeStamp" : 1635682350531,
  "title" : "",
  "userId" : "b",
  "userPhoto" : ""
},
```

This is my data structure. I'm going to make a code that delete old post by using orderbyChild(timeStamp).endAt() method when I experiment with just long variable like 1635682350531 this ->> orderbyChild(timeStamp).endAt(1635682350531l); It works when I add l to 1635682350531

And I define the current timestamp variable and put this to endAt method but It doesn't work. I may think I didn't add "l" to my variable?

Here is my code.

```
if (UId.equals("k")) {
        long tlong = System.currentTimeMillis(); long ttime;
        ttime = tlong - 3*24*60*60*1000;
        StorageReference picRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(postImage);
        showMessage(String.valueOf(ttime));
        picRef.delete()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        //image deleted, now delete database
                        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                        Query queryByTimestamp = db.child("Posts").orderByChild("timeStamp").endAt(ttime);
                        queryByTimestamp.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                                        ds.getRef().removeValue();
                                        Toast.makeText(PostDetailActivity.this,"게시글이 삭제되었습니다.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage());
                                    Toast.makeText(PostDetailActivity.this,"게시글이 삭제되지않았습니다.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            }
                        });


                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        //failed, can't go further
                        Toast.makeText(PostDetailActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Thank you for answering me.

Comment: Are you sure that `tlong - 3*24*60*60*1000` return a value that li less than `1635682350531`?

Comment: Yes I confirm about that by showmessage!

Comment: Number of digits are equal.

Comment: I cannot see how it can be equal, since  `System.currentTimeMillis()` is constantly changing, right?

Comment: Yes, showmessage method show ttime ->1635842681023 like this. I'm sorry I'm not good at english. and "less than 1635682350531?" to your comment I answered long. <ttime = tlong - 3*24*60*60*1000> is larger than 1635682350531

Comment: Oh, I see now. Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the following query:

```
Query queryByTimestamp = db.child("Posts").orderByChild("timeStamp").endAt(ttime);
```

There is an index required. So most likely the following log statement:

```
Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage());
```

Produces the following error message:

> Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "timeStamp", for path "/Posts", to the rules

To solve this, you have to set the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Posts": {
      ".indexOn": "timeStamp",
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }    
  }
}
```

In order to make it work. Having this index in place, your query will return the expected results and the following line of code:

```
ds.getRef().removeValue();
```

Will remove both children from the database.

Comment: I'm sorry but error message produces "object does not exist at location." Do you know why const is working but variable is not working?? Is it related to your answer?

Comment: That's **not** a Realtime Database error, it's a Firebase Storage error, that is coming from the `onFailure`. This basically means that you try to delete a file that doesn't exist or you are using the wrong path. This also means that onSuccess is not triggered, which also means that none of those children is deleted, right?

Comment: You can either make sure you are using the correct path when deleting the file, or you can isolate the code that is related to the Realtime Database. Give it a try and tell me if it works now.

Comment: I changed my rules but It not works. so when I deleted picRef.delete() It works! Maybe my code don't find image path.  And It works.